# Is there an equation whose solution does not exist in the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis

Just a thought... Is there an equation whose solution does not exist in the complex plane? I started thinking maybe something like $z^z = 0$. Don't know where or how to check if it's true.

P.S. I don't know which tags this question comes under (feel free to add more)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the easiest one 
 e^z=0
It doesn't have a solution in Complex plane.

Comment: Is there a proof? or someway i can check that? thanks

Comment: e^z is complex exponential if you have confusion.

Comment: Ya you can try to have a contradiction by changing it to x+iy form then putting it to zero here we may use the fact that real exponential is not zero

Comment: Another one : $1/z=0$.

Comment: Try to find a root of $f(z) = 1$.